# How to get median data from 2 Urls

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, smartcontracts, chainlink

In the below code i have 2 URLs and each url has a path

```
  These are 2 urls 
    api[0] = "https://www.bitstamp.net/api/v2/ticker/ethusd/";
    api[1] = "https://api.pro.coinbase.com/products/eth-usd/ticker";

  The path for URL 0 is last and the path for URL 1 is price
```

I want chainlink nodes to get data(last and price) from these 2 urls and  calculates median of data from 2 urls
i.e median = {last+price)/2;
How to write code for this logic in Chainlink

Answer (score 0):

First, you'd want to make 2 API calls following along with the Chainlink docs. https://docs.chain.link/docs/make-a-http-get-request/

Something like:

```js
function makeAPICall() public returns (bytes32 requestId) 
    {
        Chainlink.Request memory request = buildChainlinkRequest(jobId, address(this), this.fulfill.selector);
        request.add("get", "https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemultifull?fsyms=ETH&tsyms=USD");
        int timesAmount = 10**18;
        request.addInt("times", timesAmount);
        return sendChainlinkRequestTo(oracle, request, fee);
    }
```

Then, in your fulfil function, you'd take the medians of a list.

```js
function fulfill(bytes32 _requestId, uint256 _volume) public recordChainlinkFulfillment(_requestId)
    {
        answers.push(_volume);
        // loop through list and take median
    }
```